# automate server downtime for different servers at different days and time

Tags: bash, scripting, python

I have created script with Ansible and also with Python to put servers down in my work environment but If I can create group of all servers and set their downtime at once.

Example: If I need to put 4 servers down on Monday and bring up next day. 
Another 5 servers down (or shutdown) no Wednesday and bring up on Thursday. If I can just do it on Monday for whole week, what is the approach you suggest to make such script?

ps. I am putting servers down here every time because there is network activity in the region and its high availability environment. Just putting servers down for the region and duration when network have activity.

Comment: How do you shut the servers down and turn them on again?

Comment: Although my way is specific to environment but assume if using Dell Servers support `racadm` commands then it can be used to shutdown and power on servers.

Comment: So the script runs on a controlling node and not on the servers you want to shut down. Did you try to program the script execution in cron?